# Is it possible the navigation in webpage using coordinates in HTML5 or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation

One of my clients is asking for a webpage in one single page and somehow make the menu "redirect" to some coordinates in the page where is the information about that section. [They sent me an example](http://activeden.net/item/cool-urban-street-template-/full_screen_preview/3152) of the idea, but its maded in Flash :(

Is it possible to make something similar without flash? I don't want the job made, It will be enough with the name of the HTML tag or a simple example in jquery because I have not idea about how to start.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp section on `id attribute`

Comment: How about http://joelb.me/scrollpath/ or http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#3rdPage ?

Comment: @r4xz the scrollpath is great! it has the effect and mantains the animations between sections :)

Comment: There are also advanced posibilities like http://greensock.com/examples-showcases

Comment: What about this? http://leanproductions.co.uk/

Comment: @r4xz the scrollpath is great! it has the effect and mantains the animations between sections :) Can you please write it like an answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Scroll plugins:

- http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#4thpage
- https://ihatetomatoes.net/demos/one-page-scroll-animations/

jQuery Path plugins:

- http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

More advance solutions:

- http://greensock.com/examples-showcases (thanks to Steven Wave)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply with JQuery (JQuery UI for added shinyness).

Online example: http://jsfiddle.net/5cqgmzcb/

It doesn't work the first time you click the button for some reason, but give it a couple of tries and it basically moves it to a random generated set of XY co-ordinates of the image. With JQueryUI you have [these easing options](http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/).

JS:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var RandX = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1520) + 1);
    var RandY = Math.floor((Math.random() * 800) + 1);
    $('#container').animate({
        scrollTop: RandY, 
        scrollLeft: RandX
    },1000,'easeOutElastic');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i used this about 7 years ago on my (very old and outdated) online portfolio - http://melissahie.com

I used jquery scrollTo() function and make it point to a unique id. Then you set the id to a div (

Since i sensed that you want to do this on your own, just let me know if you want a more elaborate explanation.